# Finding a polynomial $x$ such that $x^2+3 \pmod p$ is a square

Tags: number-theory

Show a polynomial $x$ exists such that $x^2+3 \pmod p$ is a square, for all $p\geq3$ is prime.

I have tried substituting linear and quadratic polynomials for $x$ and solving for the coefficients with no success. I'm not sure how to start.

Comment: Is this supposed to hold for all $p$ simultaneously?  For one fixed $p$?

Comment: I modified the problem. I am trying to show that such a polynomial exists for all p>=3.

Comment: From your question it is not clear if $x$ is an indeterminate or a polynomial.

Comment: Has the user dissolved?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Try constant polynomials.